# Using RxJS to restore connection to the backend

Tags: angular, signalr, rxjs, observable, subject

After upgrading from AngularJS to Angular 4, I'm searching for the best way to use RxJS for restoring a websocket connection to our backend server. Our site may run in a browser or in a Cordova container. The difficulty is that at any moment the websocket connection may be lost and/or the the internet connection may be lost.

The process should be as follows:

> 1) Wait until the tablet or the website reports internet connectivity;
>
> 2) Do a signin to receive a new token in case the old one expired (external framework, returns a promise);
>
> 3) Call the start connection command every 5 seconds until connected;

At any point in time a new disconnect event may occur, but this shouldn't result in multiple reconnect processes running in parallel.

Our old AngularJS site works as expected with above process, making heavy use of deferred objects and promises. The upgraded Angular code uses a lot of promises, which makes the code unbearable to read and with a lot of edge cases:

```js
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { Response } from '../response.interface';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { SignalR, ISignalRConnection, ConnectionStatus, IConnectionOptions } from 'ng2-signalr';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ENVIRONMENT } from '../../../environments/environment';

const DISCONNECTED_STATUS = 'disconnected';
const RETRY_PERIOD = 5000;

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionAgent implements IConnectionAgent {
  public error = new Subject<Error>();
  public isConnected = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  
  private connection: ISignalRConnection;
  private waitTillOnlinePromise: Promise<void>;

  constructor(
    private signalr: SignalR,
    private AuthService: AuthService
  ) {
  }

  // Irrelevant code left out.

  /**
   * Start the reconnect process.
   */
  public startReconnect(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Start custom reconnecting...');

 // startReconnect can be called from multiple places.
    // Only start the process when reconnect isn't called earlier.
    if (this.waitTillOnlinePromise === undefined) {
      this.waitTillOnlinePromise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("startReconnect waitTillOnlinePromise === undefined. Stop connectie.");
        console.info(this.waitTillOnlinePromise);


        this.waitTillOnline().then(
          () => {
            console.info("startReconnect waitTillOnline resolved. Online, ga verbinden. Reauthorize/signin, set token opnieuw.");

            // Stop the connection, so it can be started again.
   // Not doing this step results in a connection that won't be started in certain edge cases.
            this.stopConnection();

            // get a new token just in case the old one expired while offline or (when the token is still valid) return the old token.
            this.AuthService.signin().then((token: string) => {
              console.log('startReconnect Token sucessfully received.');

              this.initHub(token);

              // reset the promise if successful, so there won't be another attempt.
              this.waitTillConnected(true).then(
                () => {
                  console.log('startReconnect waitTillConnected resolved');
                  this.waitTillOnlinePromise = undefined!;
                  resolve();
                },
                (err: Error) => { console.log('startReconnect waitTillConnected reject'); reject(err); });
            }, (err: Error) => {
              console.error('startReconnect reauthorize failed wait for 5 more seconds', err);
              this.waitTillOnline().then(() => { resolve(); console.log('startReconnect try reauthorize again resolved'); },
                                                (err) => { reject(err); console.error('startReconnect try reauthorize again reject'); });
            });

            resolve();
          }).catch(
          (err: Error) => {
            console.error("waitTillOnline waitTillOnlineTimeout error");
            console.error(err);

            this.waitTillOnlinePromise = undefined!;
            reject(err);
            this.startReconnect();
          });
      });
    }
    return this.waitTillOnlinePromise;
  }

  /**
   * Checks every 5 seconds whether the app is connected to the internet. Resolves when it does.
   */
  private waitTillOnline(): Promise<void> {
    let promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.getOnlineStatus()) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // wait 5 seconds before trying again.
          this.waitTillOnline().then(() => { console.info('waitTillOnline try again resolved'); resolve(); },
                                            (err) => {  console.error('waitTillOnline try again reject'); reject(err); });
        }, RETRY_PERIOD);
      }
    });
    return promise;
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether the device reports it has internet.
   */
  private getOnlineStatus(): boolean {
    let onlineWebApp = (navigator as any).onLine; // checks for internet connection when run as a website.
    let hasAppConnection = (navigator as any).connection; // checks for internet connection when run as a Cordova app.
    let hasConnection = onlineWebApp || (hasAppConnection !== undefined && hasAppConnection.type !== "none");

    console.log("Has a connection: " + ((hasConnection) ? "yes" : "no"));

    return onlineWebApp || (hasAppConnection !== undefined && hasAppConnection.type !== "none");
  }

  private waitTillConnected(firstCall: boolean): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Start WaitTillConnected, first call: ' + firstCall);
    let promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.isConnected.getValue()) {
        console.log('waitTillConnected Hij is verbonden!');
        resolve();
      } else {
        console.log('waitTillConnected Nog niet verbonden. Probeer opnieuw te verbinden en controleer opnieuw na 5 seconden.');
        if (this.connection !== undefined) {
          this.connection.start();
        } else {
          console.error("waitTillConnected hub/connection === undefined");
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
          // wait 5 seconds before trying again.
          this.waitTillConnected(false).then(
            () => { console.info('waitTillConnected try again resolved'); resolve(); },
            (err) => { console.warn('waitTillConnected try again reject'); reject(err); });
          }, 5000);
      }
    });

    return promise;
  }

  private stopConnection(): void {
    if (this.connection !== undefined
      && this.connection.status.last.name !== DISCONNECTED_STATUS) {
      try {
        this.connection.stop();
        console.log("stopConnection connection stop succeeded");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("stopConnection connection stop failed " + err);
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('stopConnection Connection undefined or status does not equal diconnected status. Connection not stopped.');
      console.warn(this.connection);
      console.warn(DISCONNECTED_STATUS);
      console.warn(this.connection.status.last.name !== DISCONNECTED_STATUS)
    }
  }
}
```

The above code mostly works, but it's ugly to say the least, uses getValue() which should be avoided, has a lot of if's, try/catches, resolves/rejects.

I started from scratch using RxJs's TakeUntil/TakeWhile, without using promises and unsubscribes [as being advocated here](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87). I haven't found a clean syntax which also handles frequent connection losses while reconnecting so far. Any suggestions are appreciated:

Current starting point of reconnect code:

```js
private reconnect(): void {
console.log('  - (Re)connecting');

if (this.onlineObservable == null) {
  console.log('  - Observable created (this.isOnline: ' + this.isOnline.getValue() + ')');
  this.onlineObservable = Observable.interval(1000);

  this.onlineObservable
    .takeWhile(() => this.isOnline.getValue() == false)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.checkIfOnline();
    });
}
```

- What is the best way to unsubscribe from checking the internet connection and continue with starting the SignalR connection?
- Is there a cleaner syntax in RxJs for making sure code is executed only once (or, how do you reset the observable after takeWhile/takeUntil is finished)?

**Some more context**

The app is used while driving and must be able to restore itself without the operator touching the device. We are using the SignalR framework to handle the websocket connection. It's default retry mechanism didn't restore the connection under all circumstances. The above specified process works reliably in production for a few months now.

Comment: what about making connection check via interval, and switchmap based on those? simple pseudo like –

```
const connectionCheck = Observable.interval(5000).map(() => isConnected())
const reconnectIfneeded = connectionCheck.filter((x) => !!x).switchMap(() => connect())
``` (posted as comment as I haven't verified and above code is not fully working runnable example)

Comment: Hi @OJKwon, thanks for the suggestion and the fast reply. I'll try it out after New Years eve.